# What's the point of the bear coins?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-3

Throughout the game, you can collect bear coins - up to a maximum of 99. Unlink lives, saving the game saves the number of bear coins you have. Once you get to the hidden world, Boomer mentions how he doesn't accept bear coins like the rest of his brothers. However, most of the rest of his brothers don't seem to accept them either.

As far as I know, they're useful at the beginning of the game; you need 55 for the mirror and the shell (one is 50, the other 5), each of which you trade to a bear to get a banana bird. Outside of that, all of the bears trade for prizes, and none of them accept money.

Aside from buying those first two items, is there any use for the bear coins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bear Coins can be used to purchase special items, like the mirror or shell, as mentioned. They can also be used to purchase advice from the Bazaar as well as compete against Cranky at the Swanky Sideshow tents spread throughout the world.